# Function with dynamic return type in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

In python you can define functions which dynamically return different types:

```
def func(b):
   if b:
      return 42
   else:
      return "hello"
```

How can I implement in C++ a function like this and export it with `pybind11`?

Ideally it would be something like:

```
m.def("func", [](bool b) -> py::object {
   if(b)
      return /* something */(42);
   else
      return /* something */("hello");
});
```

However, I did not find how to construct `py::object` using objects of registered C++ types.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Use `std::variant`

Comment: Ah, of course! Didn't think about that! Thanks!

Comment: You can, but should you?

Comment: It seems something not sensible to do but in connection with the new structural pattern matching it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate what an `std::variant` solution for this would look like?

Comment: @AlecJacobson I've posted the solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, thanks to @Osyotr's comment, is very simple:

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

...

m.def("func", [](bool b) -> std::variant<int, std::string> {
   if(b)
      return {42};
   else
      return {"hello"};
});
```

PyBind11 takes automatically care of providing the right component of the `variant` to the Python side.